# Reasoning about increased performance from two disjoint datasets compared to their union

Tags: machine-learning, classification, active-learning

Say I have some pretrained model with an ok but not great accuracy. I can augment my existing training data with new datasets and retrain to increase performance. Say there are two datasets available, $S_1$ and $S_2$. Let's say $f: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow [0,1]$ denotes the increase in accuracy (or another metric) when we augment our training data with a new set.

I am trying to understand the relationship between $f(S_1 \cup S_2)$ and $f(S_1) + f(S_2)$. Under what conditions is $f(S_1 \cup S_2) \leq f(S_1) + f(S_2)$ and when is it $f(S_1 \cup S_2) \geq f(S_1) + f(S_2)$. I know this depends on a host of things - like the actual datasets, the training procedure, the model, etc - but anyone could help me on how to reason about this, that would be great!